# what are the cross browser docker containers that exists for karate?

Tags: docker, ui-automation, karate, playwright

Can i able to test in different cross browsers using  docker container apart from the two existing karate-chrome containers . Since Playwright is experimental as of now ,   any other docker container works for karate to test in firefox, edge, safari and IE ?

Comment: any webdriver server or grid provider will work. and really, writing a docker container is not hard, why don't you contribute ? you are welcome to look at other solutions

Comment: @peter so, all selenium docker containers should work for karate as well ?

Comment: that is my understanding